# Controller 404 issue in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to call my a controller from another controller using redirect like so..

Welcome Controller

```
public function login(){
    $rules=array(
        array(
            'field'=>'username',
            'label'=>'Username',
            'rules'=>'required|trim'
        ),
        array(
            'field'=>'password',
            'label'=>'Password',
            'rules'=>'trim|required'
        ),
    );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
    if($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE){
        $data=array(
            'username'=>$this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username')),
            'password'=>$this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'))
        );
        $account_details=$this->users_model->getCredentials($data);

        if($account_details->num_rows()==1){
            $account_details=$account_details->result();
            $this->session->set_userdata(array('username'=>$account_details[0]->username));
            redirect(site_url('navigation'),'refresh');
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Wrong username or password.');
            $this->show_login();
        }
    }else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error',validation_errors());
        $this->show_login();
    }
}
```

Navigation Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class Navigation extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Users_access_model');
    }

    public function index(){
        $data['links']=$this->Users_access_model->get_links($this->session->userdata['username']);
        $this->load->view('common/header');
        $this->load->view('common/view_navigation');
        $this->load->view('common/scripts');
    }
    }

     ?>
```

this comes out in my addressbar

```
http://localhost/piercapitan/index.php/navigation
```

an I get this

```
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
```

This is in my config

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/piercapitan/';
```

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have used the redirect before but I was using it from my windows machine but when I transferred to Ubuntu, that is the time that I get this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Try with http://localhost/piercapitan/index.php/Navigation. Capital "N" then tell me is it working or not ? and try with this also http://localhost/piercapitan/index.php/navigation/index. and http://localhost/piercapitan/index.php/Navigation/index and try above three occurance and tell me is it still showing 404 ?

Comment: localhost/piercapitan/index.php/Navigation --> this worked for me.. How do I change my code to reflect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/piercapitan/';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';

$config['base_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';
```

Also change from

```
redirect(site_url('navigation'),'refresh');
```

to

```
redirect('/navigation','refresh');
```

or

`redirect(base_url('navigation'));`

**You will need to autoload the url helper in the file 'application/config/autoload.php'**

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this in

> application/config/config.php

```
$config ['index_page'] = '';
```